# does yodlee verifies content service credentials in ItemManegement:: addItemForContentService1 call?

Tags: yodlee

dose yodlee verify site credentials entered by user in call ItemManegement::addItemForContentService1 if startRefreshItemOnAddition = false?

we called ItemManegement::addItemForContentService1 with startRefreshItemOnAddition = false and provided wrong credentials for site. it returned itemid and does not seem to verify credentials entered.

are credentials verified only on refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Yodlee validates the user credentials only through Refresh.